# sonar.profile is deprecated for 4.5.4 Sonarqube

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube 4.5.4,and hence the **sonar.profile** is deprecated for the sonar version of 4.5.4,Please suggest what alternative tag can be used for the same.

Regards,
Namratha

Answer (score 3):

There's no replacement for this property. Instead, make your project-profile associations via the UI.

Comment: Our use case for Sonar creates new Sonar projects for each branch of our repository.  How do we automatically associate the new branch project with a (non-default) Quality Profile and Quality Gate?

Comment: That's really a new question @Mzzzzzz

Comment: Fair enough (thanks for responding): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530552/