# Sonarqube run for specific product flavor and build type (gradle plugin)

Tags: android, sonarqube, gradle-plugin

Currently we are having problems running sonarqube for just a specific build variant. for example `clienttestDebug`

Our structure is like this. We have 3 different build types

- Release
- Debug
- Profile

And has many (over 30) product flavors. For instance

```
 productFlavors {
        dev {

        }

        demo {

        }

        clienttest {

        }
        ...
     }
```

So we don't want to run the sonar to run for all variants. Normally there is a way documented as below

```
sonarqube {
    androidVariant 'clienttestDebug'
}
```

However the piece above doesn't work as expected and tries to run for all the variants. Is there something thats missing. We're using sonarqube plugin version 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out that this issue is due to addition of plugin from root build.grade.

To learn more about the gradle plugins you can read: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application

Also, to learn about adding sonarqube to multi-module projects: 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/

You have to make the addition of the plugin in your root build.gradle as follows;

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    sonarqube {
        androidVariant "clienttestDebug"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Latest sonarqube gradle api is now `sonar {  androidVariant "clienttestDebug" }`

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of sonarqube gradle plugin you must not use `sonarqube {}`, but `sonar {}` to configure the android variant.

See example below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.5.0.2730"
}

project(":app") {
    sonar {
        androidVariant 'betaDeveloperDebug'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the project level build gradle. You can run specified build variant like this.

```
project(":your_module") {
sonarqube {
    androidVariant 'your_variant'}
}
```